# MooTools - Object.contains with wildcard

Tags: javascript, mootools

I want to search for a value in an Object. For example:
I am searching for "boy". In the Object there is a value of "boy1" but Object.contains doesn't return true. Only when I actually search for "boy1".

Is it possible to use wildcards or is there any other function?

```
if(Object.contains(object, 'boy')) {
  console.log("FOUND!");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had found the answer by myself:

```
Object.each(arrayWithObjects, function(object, index) {                                                                                                                                      
   Object.each(object, function(value, key) {                                                                                                                                   
       if(value.indexOf(searchTerm) > -1) {                                                                                                                                  
           foundContacts.push(object);                                                                                                                                  
       }                                                                                                                                                                     
   });                                                                                                                                                                           
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would consider extending `Array` instead with something resembling the `where` in lodash/underscore.

```
var a = [{
    name: 'bob',
    age: 31,
    colour: 'red'
}, {
    name: 'john',
    age: 38,
    colour: 'blue',
    job: 'chef'
}];

Array.implement({
    where: function(match){
        return Array.filter(this, function(el, index){
            var allMatch = false, k;
            for (k in match){
                if (el.hasOwnProperty(k)){
                    allMatch = (typeof match[k] === 'function') ?
                        match[k].call(el, el[k], k, index) : 
                        el[k] == match[k];
                }
                else {
                    // missing key we needed
                    allMatch = false;
                }
            }
            return allMatch;
        });
    }
});

// call from native, match by string / value.
var r = Array.where(a, { name: 'bob' });
console.log('native, value match string', r);
r = Array.where(a, { age: 31 });
console.log('native, value match number', r);

// call from prototype, match by function callback
r = a.where({ 
    name: function startsWith(value, key){
        return value.indexOf('joh') === 0;
    }
});

console.log('proto, single fn', r);

// multiple matches combos
r = a.where({ 
    job: function hasAJob(job){
        return !!job.length;
    },
    age: function(age){
        return age > 35;
    },
    colour: 'red'
});

console.log('multiple matches combos', r);
```

this provides a flexible enough way to iterate your collection of objects.

in action: http://jsfiddle.net/c8gaxkny/

have a look at this fun thing i did ages ago - allows you to use CSS-like expressions to find objects in your array:

http://epitome-mvc.github.io/Epitome/#epitomecollection/find

code is at https://github.com/epitome-mvc/Epitome/blob/master/src/epitome-collection.js#L220

Answer (score 0):

You could use `var foundContacts = arrayWithObjects.filter(...` and [`Object.some()`](http://mootools.net/core/docs/1.5.1/Types/Object#Object:Object-some) to do that:

> **Object.some():**
>   Returns true if at least one value in the object satisfies the provided testing function.

```
var foundContacts = arrayWithObjects.filter(function(object){                                                                                                                                      
   return Object.some(object, function(value, key) {                                                                                                                                   
       return value.indexOf(searchTerm) > -1;                                                                                                                             
   });                                                                                                                                                                           
});
```

This way you map the initial array and dont have to iterate all keys of the object since Object.some returns early when a matching item is found.